# How to avoid writing the same function for two view controllers using subclassing and/or the delegate pattern (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers (A and B) both with the same logic:

```
  class A: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

       self.contrast(first: nil, second: self.numberOne)
           timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self,   selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


  }

  @objc private func update() {

      if count == 0 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberOne, second: self.numberTwo)
    } else if count == 1 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberTwo, second: self.numberThree)

    } else if count == 2 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberThree, second: self.numberFour)
    } else if count == 3 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberFour, second: nil)
            self.timer.invalidate()
    }

    self.count += 1
}
}

 class B: UIViewController {


  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

      self.contrast(first: nil, second: self.numberOne)
         timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self,  selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  @objc private func update() {

  if count == 0 {
        self.contrast(first: self.numberOne, second: self.numberTwo)
} else if count == 1 {
        self.contrast(first: self.numberTwo, second: self.numberThree)

} else if count == 2 {
        self.contrast(first: self.numberThree, second: self.numberFour)
} else if count == 3 {
        self.contrast(first: self.numberFour, second: nil)
        self.timer.invalidate()
}

self.count += 1
      }

    }
```

As you can see they both use the exact same code. I was attempting to solve it using an extension of UIViewController, but things got a little to messy. Then i heard about the delegate pattern, but I can't find any examples that relate to this scenario!

Edit: The viewDidAppear method is also the exact same. If somehow I could override that from a superclass?

Comment: You should use a switch count instead of using multiple else's

Comment: Is this *all* the code for both view controllers? If so, then why the need for two separate classes? `ClassA` is *already a subclass of `UIViewController`, and just instantiate two instances (or set the class in IB) of `ClassA`.

Comment: -->Sub-classing: You can create class say myClass from UIViewController and use it as super class of your class A and B, and white common business logic in myClass and call that methods

Comment: As you are using self as object ref. you have to update methods and property if you planning to work with delegates and protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are several ways to avoid repeating code. The problem is  you should know the logic of these classes and how they relate to each other to decide how to implement them.

First of all, these two classes are completely the same. Do you have another different code in these classes? If no, you don't need 2 same classes, just leave 1 class.

If yes, than it depends on which other code each class implements. For example, if your B class should be exactly the same as A class and inherit all of its features but also add some new features, then it looks like class B is a child class of A class.

```
classA: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.contrast(first: nil, second: self.numberOne)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self,   selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc private func update() {
        if count == 0 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberOne, second: self.numberTwo)
        } else if count == 1 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberTwo, second: self.numberThree)
        } else if count == 2 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberThree, second: self.numberFour)
        } else if count == 3 {
            self.contrast(first: self.numberFour, second: nil)
            self.timer.invalidate()
        }
        self.count += 1
    }
}

classB: classA {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        addNewFeatures()
    }

    func addNewfeatures {
        //some additional code
    }
}
```

If two classes are different and not related to each other like Parent-Child, you could shift common behavior in some protocol, add default implementation to this protocol via extension and indicate that your classes will implement this protocol.

```
protocol Contrasting {
    func contrast(first:Int, second: Int)
}

extension Contrasting {
    func contrast(first: Int, second: Int) {
        //make contrast
    }
}

classA: UIViewController, Contrasting {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        contrast(first: nil, second: self.numberOne)
    }
}

classB: UIViewController, Contrasting {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        contrast(first: nil, second: self.numberOne)
    }
}
```

https://krakendev.io/blog/subclassing-can-suck-and-heres-why read this tutorial to know when use inheritance and protocols.

Please, use switch when working with numbers to avoid a lot of else if statements.

```
switch count {
    case 0:
        self.contrast(first: self.numberOne, second: self.numberTwo)
    case 1:
        self.contrast(first: self.numberTwo, second: self.numberThree)
    case 2:
        self.contrast(first: self.numberThree, second: self.numberFour)
    case 3:
        self.contrast(first: self.numberFour, second: nil)
    default:
        break
}
```

Comment: Please delete the `break` statements after case `1-3`. Swift's `switch` cases *break* implicitly.

Comment: @vadian Oh, you're right, sorry. I've edited the answer. Thanks!